# ImmutableJS Counter not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, immutability, immutable.js

I must be going wrong somewhere, but I can't figure out where.
I am trying to get things going with ImmutableJS:

```
  case 'GET_NEXT_PERSON': {
    var counter = state.get('counter');
    counter++;
    var newState = state.set('counter', counter);
    return newState;
  }
```

The counter does not increment though. A hint would be appreciated!

`state` looks like this:

```
const initialState = Map({ counter: 0 });
```

and is then put into the reducer as usual:

```
export default function (state=initialState, action) {
... }
```

Comment: Are you switching the `state` reference to `newState` somewhere? Otherwise this wont work.

Comment: I seem to not understand... ? (so probably, I am then *not* switching the reference - how could I do that?)

Comment: Please share more code. How's the `state` variable maintained?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code should work, so I'm thinking the problem might be elsewhere in your app. But you can simplify what you have here a little.

Increment a value in one line by using `update`:

```
case 'GET_NEXT_PERSON':
  return state.update('counter', value => value + 1);
```